# Access or alter data from ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, itemcollection

i have a simple listview like that

```
<ListView Name="CoordinateList" Margin="2"
                  Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Nr}"  Header="Nr." Width="40"/>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding X}" Header="X" Width="100"/>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Y}" Header="Y" Width="100"/>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Q}" Header="Q" Width="40"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

i can add items, sort or remove them e.g.:

```
CoordinateList.Items.Add(new Coordinate() { Nr = 1, X = 230, Y = 530, Q = 2 });
```

but how can i access or alter the data now? this doesn't give me the properties of `Coordinate`:

```
CoordinateList.Items[i].
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ListView stores its `Items` collection as objects, so in order to access an item as a `Coordinate` object, you need to cast it to a `Coordinate` type first. E.g.:

```
var coord = (Coordinate) CoordinateList.Items[i];
...
```

Edit: Also see @Muds' answer for better practice.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to bind you ListView with a collection, and then add remove or access objects from that collection.

Relying on UI Controls for data manipulation from code behind is not advisable.

```
<ListView Name="CoordinateList" ItemsSource="{Binding MyNewList}" Margin="2"
                  Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Nr}"  Header="Nr." Width="40"/>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding X}" Header="X" Width="100"/>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Y}" Header="Y" Width="100"/>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Q}" Header="Q" Width="40"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Then,

```
public ObservableCollection<Coordinate> MyNewList { get; set;}

MyNewList.Add(new Coordinate() { Nr = 1, X = 230, Y = 530, Q = 2 })

MyNewList[I] --> will have your item.
```